# Random x count of lines from each group without looping

Tags: sql-server

I am seeking to get 25 random lines from each agency in a specific timeframe.  Here is a script I came up with:

```
DECLARE @dateStart DATE,
        @dateEnd DATE,
        @agency varchar(8)

set @dateStart = '9/1/2016'
set @dateEnd = '9/30/2016'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp_THISDATA', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #tmp_THISDATA

CREATE TABLE #tmp_THISDATA(
    [ACCOUNT] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [AGENCY_CODE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [THE_DATE] [DATETIME] NOT NULL)

DECLARE agencies CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT [AGENCY_CODE]
FROM [dbo].[CORE_DATA] dial
WHERE CAST([THE_DATE] AS DATE) BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd

OPEN agencies
FETCH NEXT FROM agencies   
INTO @agency

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO #tmp_THISDATA
    SELECT TOP 25
           [ACCOUNT]
          ,[AGENCY_CODE]
          ,[THE_DATE]
    FROM [dbo].[CORE_DATA] dial
    WHERE CAST([THE_DATE] AS DATE) BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
      AND AGENCY_CODE = @agency
    ORDER BY NEWID()
END

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_THISDATA
```

This works but is running very long.  It's an ugly data set and there are some efforts to optimize it, but I suspect that eliminating the looping will also speed it up, if such a thing is feasible.

Can the loop be eliminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
INSERT INTO #tmp_THISDATA
SELECT [ACCOUNT],
       [AGENCY_CODE],
       [THE_DATE]
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY AGENCY_CODE ORDER BY Newid() ) AS rn,
               [ACCOUNT],
               [AGENCY_CODE],
               [THE_DATE]
        FROM   [dbo].[CORE_DATA] dial
        WHERE  [THE_DATE] > dateadd(dd,-1,@dateStart) and [THE_DATE] <= @dateEnd) a
WHERE  rn <= 25
```

Comment: I've forgotten about this!  Running both queries now, my script has a 42 minute head start... we'll see how they both fare.

Comment: @n8. This will be much faster than your current `while` loop approach

Comment: I certainly expect that to be the case

Comment: @n8. - Just made a small change to the `Where` clause to make use of any index available on `THE_DATE` column

Comment: "between" doesn't make use of an index?

Comment: @n8. No the use of `CAST` function on `THE_DATE` column will make the optimiser not to use `INDEX`

Comment: OOoooooh right, that's one of the current efforts to clean up that table.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a CROSS APPLY

```
Select Distinct A.Account
      ,B.Agency_Code
      ,B.The_Date
 From  [dbo].[CORE_DATA] A
 Cross Apply (Select Top 25 Agency_Code,Agency_Code 
               From  [dbo].[CORE_DATA] 
               Where Account=A.Account and The_Date between @dateStart AND @dateEnd
               Order By NewID()
              ) B
```

Comment: @n8  Hard to say Prdp is a valued resource.  Like chicken soup for a cold... couldn;t hurt to try

Comment: Looking at this I have some other questions: I pared out a lot of columns to simplify and homogenize the query for public consumption.  If I have other `WHERE` conditions it seems like I would need to have those in both 'SELECT' statements as well, yes?

Comment: @n8. I see you selected the answer.  I suspect the additional where conditions would only be required in the top select (presuming that would pair down to the appropriate Accounts).   Just curious on the performance.  It seems like you have a large table

Comment: Prdp's query ran in a minute, mine is still running 76 minutes later, yours is 8 minutes and counting, I'm sure it will ultimately be better than my solution but the preference is pretty clear to me.  The table I am querying against is 46gb, growing daily, and is indexed but with dates saved as varchars so I suspect it is not optimized.

Comment: @n8 Kill mine.  No need to test further.

Comment: Yeah I'm killing mine too.  Thanks for the feedback!